# gitlab install is stuck at 0% on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, gitlab

i am trying to install GitLab on ubuntu 14.04

I am ok installing the first bit

```
curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh \
| sudo bash
```

however when i go to install the next bit

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

All i get is "0% [Working] and thats it nothing else happens, does anyone have any ideas???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look with "apt-get update" if all goes well there.

Comment: It seems the percentage is not updating, I just had to wait 30 mins for the download to finish (then run into the hash-error, but that's another story I have to solve).

Answer (score 5):

See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/628,
the issue still seems ongoing.

EDIT: Doing `apt-get clean` and then `apt-get upgrade --fix-missing` worked for me.